# Cypress Best Practice - Store and compare two values

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to store a value, then perform an action and assert that the value has not changed. I do have a code that works but I would like to have input if there is a more elegant solution.

The basic idea is:

- Get the number or results displayed ('counts'), store it in a .then() function
- Change the use
- Get the number of results displayed ('new_counts'), store it in a new .then function
- Compare counts and new_counts in the 2nd .then() function

```js
describe('Store and compare a value', () => {
    it('store and compare', () => {

        cy.login()
        cy.visit('url2')
        cy.get('.total-count-results').invoke('text')
            .then((text) => {
                const counts = text 
                cy.get('.medium.col100 > .filterwrapper > input').type('Test Dummy',{force: true})
                cy.get('.medium.col100 > .filterwrapper > input').type('{enter}')
                cy.get('.total-count-results').invoke('text')
                    .then((text) => {
                        const new_counts = text
                        expect(new_counts).to.eq(counts)
                    })
            })
    })
})
```

That is the best I could come up with to handle asynchronicity.

Comment: You could simplify by actually naming the arrow function parameters what you want the variables to be called, and asserting directly rather than nesting another then, but otherwise this is what https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases suggests.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at that part of the documentation again. Also, thanks for editing my post to match SO standards better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use aliases for this and do something like this:

```js
describe('Store and compare a value', () => {
  it('store and compare', () => {
    cy.login()
    cy.visit('url2')
    cy.get('.total-count-results').invoke('text').as('counts')
    cy.get('.medium.col100 > .filterwrapper > input').type('Test Dummy', {
      force: true,
    })
    cy.get('.medium.col100 > .filterwrapper > input').type('{enter}')
    cy.get('.total-count-results').invoke('text').as('new_counts')
    cy.get('@counts').then((counts) => {
      cy.get('@new_counts').then((new_counts) => {
        expect(new_counts).to.eq(counts)
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks definitely much better. I was not sure how to use aliases correctly, but in the future I will try to implement this feature!

Comment: the second alias reference should be "cy.get('@new_counts')"

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have corrected the typo.

Comment: Thx a lot I will implement it and do in future a YouTube video on german "Never Code Alone" channel

Answer (score 8):

I don't think aliases are required. Here is my solution that I tested locally. I kept most of the code in Alapan Das' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69360094/10117759) so it's easier to compare. To me, it seems more concise and easier to read without aliases.

```
describe('Store and compare a value', () => {
    it('store and compare', () => {  
        cy.login()
        cy.visit('url2')
        cy.get('.total-count-results').invoke('text')
            .then((previousText) => {
                cy.get('.medium.col100 > .filterwrapper > input').type('Test Dummy',{force: true})
                cy.get('.medium.col100 > .filterwrapper > input').type('{enter}')
                cy.get('.total-count-results').invoke('text').should("eq", previousText)
            })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

A good solution for comparing values like this can be to use a closure variable, as per the example in Cypress' documentation at https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Compare-text-values-of-two-elements. In your example, something like this:

```js
describe('Store and compare a value', () => {
    it('store and compare', () => {

        let counts // closure variable
        cy.login()
        cy.visit('url2')
        cy.get('.total-count-results').invoke('text')
            .then(text => counts = text)     // set closure variable

        cy.get('.medium.col100 > .filterwrapper > input').type('Test Dummy',{force: true})
        cy.get('.medium.col100 > .filterwrapper > input').type('{enter}')

        cy.get('.total-count-results').invoke('text')
            .then(new_counts => expect(new_counts).to.eq(counts))   // compare closure variable
            //.should("eq",counts)  // won't work: counts still undefined when run
    })
})
```

This is reasonably concise, and avoids having nested '.then' clauses, which can become like callback hell as complexity grows.

(See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures for background on closures: in short, "a closure gives you access to an outer function's scope from an inner function". The inner functions here are the two `.then` functions: they access the `counts` variable from the outer `it` function's scope.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm comparing 4 variables and this saved me a hell of nested statements. I'm wondering what happened to async/await? Why does cypress not support it?

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#Commands-Are-Asynchronous might help. (Baldly summarised, Cypress has its own non-Promise based structures because timing commands against a DOM is complicated).

Comment: ...or in their own words: "Why can't I use async / await? If you're a modern JS programmer you might hear "asynchronous" and think: why can't I just use async/await instead of learning some proprietary API? Cypress's APIs are built very differently from what you're likely used to: but these design patterns are incredibly intentional. We'll go into more detail later in this guide. "